# The compiled C-code cannot be executed. Access denied

Tags: c, mingw, access-denied

I installed MinGw gcc compiler but I am not able to execute any C-code I compiled. For some reason every time I try to execute the .exe file I get the message: Access denied

I installed MinGW with the installer: mingw-get-setup.exe

My code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    printf("test");

    return 0;
}
```

To compile I simply write: gcc -o Test Test.c

I tried it in my github folder and on the desktop but i get the same error:

```
Access is denied.
```

Windows 10

Comment: Would you mind to provide some more details? It's not that I would be able to help you because I don't run Win10 at home, but for others to help you. Which MinGW did you install how, how do you write what source code, how do you compile and link it, where do you expect the executable, is it there, and how is the error reported?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are are unable to execute a file in Windows 10 often that's because of the permissions attached to it.

Right click on directory containing your executable and click properties. On the security tab select advanced options. You will now have an option to change the ownership of the directory.

You can also use [`takeown`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753024.aspx) from the command prompt to take ownership a folder, all its sub folders and files recursively:

```
takeown /f "c:\folder\subfolder" /r
```

If the problem is still not resolved it may be due to execute permissions. On the security tab of the directory check that execution is not denied.

You can alternatively use [`icacls`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/icacls) from the command prompt to reset the  the broken permissions:

```
icacls "C:\folder\subfolder" /reset /T
```